# How to convert this C-Code to MIPS Assembly-Code

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I need help with understanding the mips-code.

I don't understand the first two lines where we get k to 4k.

What is the purpose of that?
Thanks a lot in advance

[image: That is the code]

Comment: Code in text format always helps

Comment: `sizeof(int)==4` so you need to scale by 4.

Comment: Please provide code in text form. All textual informaion is more useful in textual form. It can be copied, searched, pasted into our own IDE, ... After all, you DO want to make helping you easy, don't you?

Comment: _Side note:_ Just as in C, we can change `x = y * 4` [or `x = y + y; x = x + x`] into `x = y << 2`. So, we can replace the first two asm lines with: `sll $t0,$a1,2`

Answer (score 1):

$a0 contains the address in memory of the table 'v' and $a1 the value contained by 'k'.
The code speaks for itself when you know that an 'int' occupies 4 bytes in memory.
By multiplying k by 4, we obtain the memory offset of the table 'v'. For example, if v is at the address 1000h, &v[0] = 1000h, &v[1] = 1004h, &v[2] = 1008h, ...